# Is there a rational number between any two irrationals?

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Suppose $i_1$ and $i_2$ are distinct irrational numbers with $i_1 < i_2$.  Is it necessarily the case that there is a rational number $r$ in the interval $[i_1, i_2]$?  How would you construct such a rational number?

[I posted this only so that the useful answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414036/rationals-and-irrationals-on-the-real-number-line/414048#414048 could be merged here before that question was deleted.]

Comment: Yes, there is. This is known as the "density of the rationals in the reals", which says in fact that between any two reals numbers there is a rational number.

Comment: Related: [Show that $\Bbb Q $ is dense in the real numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226793/show-that-mathbbq-is-dense-in-the-real-numbers-using-supremum)

Comment: So, wait... you asked the question, pointed to another question that already answers this... and then answered this question several days before asking it?  **TIME TRAVELER!!!**

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yeah, I thought that, then I read the [bit in brackets in the question].

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\neq y$. Without loss of generality, suppose $x<y$. Then there exists a positive $z$ such that $y-x=z$.

By Archimedes' axiom, there exists a natural number $n$ such that
$$n > \dfrac{1}{z}$$
$$nz > 1$$
$$ny - nx > 1$$
So there exists an integer $m$ such that
$$nx < m < ny$$
$$x < \frac{m}{n} < y$$
i.e. $m/n$ is a rational number between $x$ and $y$.

Since $x$ and $y$ can be any real numbers, in particular they can be irrationals.

Comment: How do you know $\exists m\in\mathbb Z:nx<m<ny$?

Comment: Hadn't really worked it out formally, but I think this works. Seems a bit complicated -- I'd be happy to hear an improvement. Let $a=nx, b=ny$. We want to show $b-a>1\implies\exists m\in\mathbb{Z},\ a<m<b$. Assume $b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\lfloor b \rfloor=b$, so $\lfloor b \rfloor-y>1$ and $\lfloor b \rfloor-1>y$ is your $m$. Now assume $b\notin\mathbb{Z}$, so $\lfloor b \rfloor<b<\lfloor b \rfloor+1$. Then $b-a>1\implies b>a+1\implies \lfloor b \rfloor+1>a+1$ and $\lfloor b \rfloor>y$ is your $m$.

Comment: @AlexD It seems I mixed in a $y$ in a few places where there should be an $a$. Sorry about that. Too late to edit. Hopefully it is still clear.

Comment: No worries, I was asking because I was trying to understand the proof myself for my intro to analysis class. I found the step in another proof:  $nx\in\mathbb R\implies\exists w\in\mathbb Z:w\le nx<w+1\implies w+1\le nx+1<(nx+(ny-nx)=ny)\implies nx<w+1<ny.$ Then $\exists m\in\mathbb Z:m=w+1\implies nx<m<ny$.

Comment: we can specifically choose $n = \lceil \frac{1}{z} \rceil$, and $m = \lceil n \times x \rceil$

Comment: Say that you have, $ny-nx>1$. Then you have $ny-1>nx$. Now, we know that, between $ny$ and $ny-1$ there exists a integer $m$ such that $ny>m≥ny-1$. Hence there exists a integer $m$, such that, $ny>m>nx$.

Comment: Even simpler: $ny - nx > 1.$ Now, the minimum difference of every two integers is $1$ (if and only if the integers are consecutive). This means that there is at least one integer point in the interval, $[nx, ny]$, call it $m$.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but anw why are we comparing n with 1/z necessarily? couldn't we just do n > z instead?

Comment: In my reply I suggested the specific example of finding a rational number $\sqrt2 < r < \sqrt3-\frac14$.  Let's try that here. Following the nomenclature in this post, we have $z = (\sqrt3- \frac14)-\sqrt 2  \approx 0.0678$ .  This is larger than $\frac1{15} \approx 0.067$  so we may take $n=15$.  Then there should be an integer $m$ with $21.21\approx 15\sqrt2 < m < 15(\sqrt3-\frac14) \approx 22.23$.   We can (and must) take $m=22$. Then the rational number we have computed is $r =\frac nm = \frac{22}{15} \approx 1.467$, which is correct.

Answer (score 29):

Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct irrationals; we lose no generality to suppose $a<b$.  Assume they have equal integer parts, since otherwise there is an integer between them and the question is trivial. They have infinite decimal expansions, $.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ and $.b_1b_2b_3\ldots$.  These cannot agree in every position since otherwise $a=b$.  So say they agree up to the $n-1$th position and differ at the $n$th.  Then $$ x= \;.b_1b_2b_3\ldots b_n 0000000\ldots$$

is a rational number strictly between $a$ and $b$:

$$\begin{align}
a &= \;.a_1a_2\ldots a_{n-1}a_n\ldots \\& <\; .a_2a_2\ldots a_{n-1}b_n000\ldots &= x
\end{align}$$

because $a_n < b_n$, and

$$\begin{align}
x & = \;.b_1b_2b_3\ldots b_n 0000000\ldots \\ & < \;.b_1b_2b_3\ldots b_nb_{n+1}\ldots & = b
\end{align}$$

because not all of $b_{n+1}, b_{n+2}, \ldots$ can be zero.

For example, there is a rational number betwen $\sqrt2 = 1.4142\ldots$ and $\sqrt3 -\frac14 = 1.482\ldots$; this method produces the rational number $1.48000\ldots = \frac{37}{25}$.  You can of course do the same thing in base 2; then you get $x = 1._20111000\ldots = \frac{23}{16}$, which also works.

It would also be fairly easy to produce a similar argument based on the continued fraction expansions of $a$ and $b$, but I think this is simpler.

Comment: Your proof contradicts itself by not allowing integers but allowing integers up to b_n.

Comment: One of us is confused, and I bet it's you. $b_n$ is not an integer.  It is a decimal digit.  And my proof doesn't "disallow" integers; it observes that if $a$ and $b$ have different integer parts then there is no need for a proof because there is an integer between them and the question is answered.

Comment: So then extend this to n decimal places.

Comment: I guess this shows that you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink.

Comment: Irrational numbers are defined as numbers that do not contain any pattern for base representations of any kind as n goes to Infiniti. How then, can you claim that there is no two real numbers such that they are equivalent for all finite n and contain their incongruity at the infinite number place. If this is not true then I could conjecture that, due to the finite nature of the possibility range of irrationals, irrationals are countably infinite.

Comment: @Daniel: There is no "infinite number place." Your conception of the notation "$\infty$" as a number (or occasionally a cardinality) seems to be at the root of all of your confusion.

Comment: If there is no non-discernible number place than explain how Q is not a completion of R, or how R/Q can even exist.

Comment: @Daniel: Ah! Did you not mean "decimal place" when you said "number place"?

Comment: @CameronBuie yes that is what I meant. :)

Comment: There is one minor error i think. if a and b are integers there doesn't have to be an integer between the. For example there is no integer between 2 and 3. Of course finding a rational number between integers is trivial.

Comment: @JensSchauder If a has integer part 2 and b has integer part 3 and *b is irrational*, then 3 is indeed between a and b.

Comment: @Joseph oh, I see.

Comment: There is another exposition of the same idea in [this post of Alex Basson](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/18977/25554).

Comment: @DanielMargolis You seem to be thinking of real numbers as hyper-real numbers. 0.999... = 1 precisely for the reason that there are no infinitely small differences between two real numbers. The difference between any two real numbers is always larger than some rational number. So, for an example, the difference between Sqrt(2) and Sqrt(3)-1/4 is larger than 1/20. Q is not the completion of R because Q is contained in R. Just because irrational numbers are approximated by real numbers doesn't mean they are rational. The expansions are not the same forever, even if they are the same for a while.

Answer (score 14):

You can apply an "argument from authority" here :). As we all know, Dedekind constructed a one-to-one correspondence between the real numbers and certain sets of rational numbers, which he called "cuts". We all accept that Dedekind's construction of the real numbers is mathematically flawless. By the way these cuts are constructed (see his 1872 paper), if there would be two irrational numbers without a rational number in between, then these two irrational numbers would correspond to the same Dedekind Cut. That would imply that there is no one-to-one correspondence between the real numbers and his cuts, hence Dedekind's construction of the reals would be incorrect (--> contradiction).

Comment: +1 That's a really interesting argument. Never thought of that before.

Answer (score 12):

We can construct one explicitly. Assume $0\lt a \lt b$. Let $n= \max(2,\lceil \frac 2{b-a}\rceil)$. Then let $m=\lceil na \rceil$ and $a \lt \frac m n \lt b$

Comment: Take a = pi and b = 2pi. n = 2, and m = 1. 1/2 is less than pi.

Comment: @DanielMargolis:  I had an error in both versions.  The $a$ should not have been in the denominator

Comment: What of a and b infinitesimally close together?

Comment: @DanielMargolis:  in the standard reals, there are no such.  You (or the problem poser) have to specify them first and the difference will not be infinitesimal.  It may be small, which makes $n$ large, but that is OK.  Even if $a=\sqrt 2, b=\sqrt 2 + 10^{-100}$ this works.

Comment: But then R is not complete.

Comment: @DanielMargolis:  Yes, it is.  In fact, if you extend $\Bbb R$ with infinitesimals, it becomes incomplete.  If you have an infinitesimal $\epsilon$, the set $\{\frac 1n|n \in \Bbb N\}$ has $0$ as a lower bound, but it has no greatest lower bound.

Comment: But the infinitesimals are all irrational and come in packets uninterrupted by rationals. Therefore rationals do not bisect or disallow contact between every 2 irrationals.

Comment: If you are working in some number system that includes infinitesimals, you should say that.  There is no indication in the question that you are, and all the answers to this and your other question are in the real numbers.  I know very little about such systems.  You seem to have an intuitive sense of how you want the infinitesimals to behave, but I don't think they can act that way.

Comment: Infinitesimals are included by construction of$ R$

Comment: @Daniel: Which construction of $R$ are you referring to? There are several.

Comment: The construction that includes all irrationals found by functions using countable infinity combined in multiplication with all rationals in union with all rationals.

Comment: Roots of positive functions included.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm afraid I don't understand your description of the construction. Could you provide a link?

Comment: @CameronBuie:  the idea is to find $n$ large enough so that $\frac 1n \lt b-a$.  Then at least one of the numbers $\frac mn$ will fit into the interval.  I actually didn't need the factor $2$.  Think about $a=\pi, b=\sqrt {10}$.  Then $b-a \approx 0.0207, n=97, m=304, \frac mn \approx 3.134, \pi \lt 3.134 \lt \sqrt {10}$

Comment: @Ross: I understand your answer (and upvoted it). I was wondering about the construction Daniel was referring to that includes infinitesimals. If he's working with a non-standard construction of the reals, that may explain a great deal of his confusion.

Comment: @CameronBuie:  yes, he is including infinitesimals, which comes out late in this discussion, as well as another question he asks.  Then he wants to lump all infinitesimals with the standard irrationals.  I am not sure if it is confusion or trolling.

Comment: If irrationals do not have an infinite decimal place then there is a rational representation of every irrational number. Suppose $\pi=3.14$. Then $\pi=\frac{22}{5}$. The same holds if $irr=$ any finite list.

Comment: Irrationals exist in packets infinitesimally close to one another.

Comment: @Daniel: Noone is claiming that irrationals have finite decimal expansions--their definitions do indeed have infinitely many decimal places. What do you mean by "***an*** infinite decimal place," though?

Comment: @DanielMargolis I think you're getting confused. Given a real number, the NEXT real number would be infinitesimally close to it, however we do not have a notion of a NEXT real number. In any case, even if we do, we couldn't describe this difference using real numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Be $a$ and $b$ two irrational numbers, with $a<b$. Since $a<b$, we have $b-a>0$. Now there are rational numbers arbitrary close to $0$, and therefore there's a rational number $q<b-a$. Now consider the set $M=\{qn: n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Now be $q_l$ the largest element of $M$ less than $a$, and $q_r$ the smallest element of $M$ greater than $b$. Clearly $q_r-q_l > b-a$. However, if there's no rational number between $a$ and $b$, then there's especially no element of $M$ between $a$ and $b$, because all elements of $M$ are rational. But then $q_r$ is the element of $M$ following $q_l$, that is, $q_r-q_l = q$. But by construction, $q<b-a$, so we have $b-a < q_l-q_r = q < b-a$ which is a contradiction. Therefore there's at least one element of $M$, which is a rational number, in between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: If you pick the right a and b, their difference is not contained, by definition, in Q, the set of all rationals.

Comment: @DanielMargolis: I didn't claim it is.

Comment: In what sense is b - a > 0. You claim that for every irrational epsilon > 0, there is a rational epsilon - delta > 0, for some epsilon > delta > 0.

Comment: The real numbers are totally ordered, that means exactly one of $a-b>0$, $a-b=0$, $a-b<0$ is true. $a-b=0$ would mean $a=b$, but by assumption, $a$ and $b$ are different (were $a=b$, quite trivially there would be no rational number between $a$ and $b$). So this leaves $a-b>0$ and $a-b<0$. I further assumed that $a$ denotes the smaller of the two, i.e. $a<b$, which is equivalent to $b-a>0$. So $b-a>0$ by the initial assumption (but that's just a wlog assumption; if we had $a<b$, you could just use $a-b$ instead).

Comment: Is there always an R closer to 0 than any Q?

Comment: @DanielMargolis: There cannot be such an $R$ because all sequences of rational numbers whose absolute value eventually stays beyond any given rational number converge to $0$. So any number that is closer to $0$ than any rational number cannot be the limit of a sequence of rational numbers, in contradiction to $\mathbb{R}$ being the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Take Q 1/n for n in N. I chose this because 1 is the smallest positive integer and we want to take q in Q as small as possible. As n goes to Infiniti q reaches epsilon > 0. Now take 1/n*irr where irr is an irrational less than 1. This is obviously an irrational number and always less than q. Since there are infinitely many irrational numbers less than 1, there are infinitely many irrationals between 0 and epsilon.

Comment: $1/n*irr$ is not an irrational number, it is a whole *sequence* of irrational numbers. And not a single one is closer to $0$ than *all* rational numbers. Yes, for every rational number (with the exception of $0$ itself, of course), there's an irrational number that's closer to $0$. But there's no irrational number which is closer to $0$ than every rational number, because for each irrational number there's a rational number which is *even closer* to $0$.

Comment: I just gave an example for every n in /mathbb(N) and irr between (epsilon, 1). Prove that for the same /mathbb(N) there is a /mathbb(Q) closer to 0 than Irr = /mathbb(R) / /mathbb(Q).

Comment: You did *not* provide a *single* irrational number that is closer to $0$ than *any* rational number. Nowhere did I claim there is no irrational number arbitrary close to $0$. But there's always a rational number *even closer* to $0$.

Comment: You are thinking finitely in terms of examples. If you could give any example, I could give you a subset of Q and Irr that conforms to your ideology, both of which are countably infinite, both of which contain an equivalent number of values that can be listed in an integer sequence.

Comment: No, I was giving a general argument. It was *you* who gave a "counterexample". Of course when explaining why your counterexample isn't one I was talking about that example. But my arguments were all completely general. And there is no "ideology" in the real numbers. And I don't doubt that you can give me countable sets of irrational numbers. But that doesn't matter the slightest bit for the question at hand. I've given an argument why there can't be an irrational number closer to $0$ than any rational number (i.e. one where's no rational number closer to $0$ than that irrational number). If …

Comment: … you want to claim that argument is wrong, you have to either point out a logical flaw, or give a valid counterexample to it. Neither you did. You gave a "counterexample" which wasn't one.

Comment: If the distance from a in Q to 0 is equal to the distance from b in Irr to 0, and neither is negative. We are constructing distance in R. Then a = b and further, for every a in Q there is a b in Irr. This contradicts the definition Irr = R / Q.

Comment: "If the distance from a in Q to 0 is equal to the distance from b in Irr to 0, and neither is negative." That situation cannot occur. I'm starting to think you're just trolling. EOD.

Comment: "I've given an argument why there can't be an irrational number closer to 0 than any rational number (i.e. one where's no rational number closer to 0 than that irrational number)."

Comment: Do you *really* not know the difference between "thhere is no irraltional number closer to $0$ than any rational number" (true) and "for any rational number there is no irrational number closer to it" (false)? In that case, do yourself a favour and learn elementary logic.

Comment: "One where there's no irrational number closer to 0 than rational number [closer to zero]."