# Verify proof that for all $r \in (0, 1)$ and $0 < m < 1$, there exists $x \in (0, m)$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n + x$ is a multiple of $r$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove a more complicated theorem, but I'm stuck on a part of the proof which I have condensed to the following lemma, which I want verification of:

**Lemma:** For all irrational $r \in (0, 1)$ and real $0 < m < 1$, there exists a real $x \in (0, m)$ and an integer $n$ such that $n + x$ is a multiple of $r$.

*Proof.* We want $n + x = rk$ for some integer $k$. Then $$x = rk - n,$$ and $$\text{frac}(x) = \text{frac}(rk - n) = \text{frac}(rk).$$ So we need
$$x = \text{frac}(rk)$$
for some integer $k$. If for integer $j$ we have
$$j \leq rk < j + 1,$$
then
$$x = \text{frac}(rk) = rk - j,$$
which we require for some $0 < x < m$. Then all we need is
$$0 < rk - j < m,$$
$$j < rk < j + 1$$
for some integers $k, j$.
Manipulating the second equation gives us
$$0 < rk - j < m,$$
$$0 < rk - j < 1.$$
Since $m < 1$ we need only look at the first equation. Then we have
$$0 < rk - j < m$$
$$\frac{j}{k} < r < \frac{j}{k} + \frac{m}{k}.$$
Then all we need is to find a rational number $\alpha = \frac{j}{k}$ so that
$$\alpha < r < \alpha + \beta,$$
where $\beta = \frac{m}{k} > 0$. Because the [rationals are dense in the reals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421580/is-there-a-rational-number-between-any-two-irrationals), such an $\alpha$ must exist between the two real numbers $r - \beta$ and $r$ for *any* $\beta > 0$, that is,
$$r - \beta < \alpha < r.$$
Such an $\alpha$ satisfies the above requirement that
$$\alpha < r < \alpha + \beta,$$
and the proof is complete.

---

Does this all seem right? The only thing I can think of that might not work is the last part, where I say that $\alpha$ exists between $r - \beta$ and $r$. Does the fact that $\beta$ depends on $\alpha$ matter for this statement?

Otherwise, is there anything I can do to simplify the proof or make it more clear?

Comment: While this nicely shows how to arrive at the desired result, a proof would typically be written exactly backwards ...

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I was just thinking that! I'm writing the proof the way I derived it: showing necessary properties about the answer and then showing the existence of the answer. I could start with the existence, and then show that its properties satisfy the lemma.

Comment: Wait a minute. You find $\alpha$ in terms of $\beta$, in terms of $k$, which is to be determined. That's not so clean ... (Actually, after rewriting to "backwards mode" you might have noticed that as well)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yup. That's the part I'm still not sure about. It seems "unclean", as you say, but I can't find any contradiction from it.... yet.