# Show that each real number is a Sup

Tags: real-analysis

Show that each real number is the supremum of a set of a rational numbers and also the supremum of a set of irrational numbers. He is what i got so far. Let $$Q= [m/n | m,n \in Z, where n \not=0]$$ The set $Q$ is not empty since $0 \in Q$. Since Q is not empty by the completeness axiom $Q$ is bounded above. So by definition there is a number $a \in R$ such that $a=SupQ$, Now the question is how do how show that $a$ is the supremum. I know that it is supposed to simple but i am having a hard time showing a is the least upper bound

Comment: Not every non-empty set is bounded from above.

Comment: What is your model of a "real number"?

Comment: Yeah in this particular problem the teacher told me that the set is bounded above so this part is true

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in the real numbers. (Using Supremum)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226793/show-that-mathbbq-is-dense-in-the-real-numbers-using-supremum)